# Animating objects while simulating water

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

I can animate objects, move them, rotate them, etc and create an animation from that.  I can also create a fluid simuation, bake that and create a little video from that.  But now I want to create a wave simulation where I have a tank of water and the tank is rocked up and down and the water inside "sloshes" from one end to the other.  Then I can play around with timing and angle of the contain being tipped to create some cool waves.  But I am having trouble mixing a fluid physics simulation with the animation of the tank holding the water.

Either I'm missing something or it's a lot harder than I think it is.

I read online that I need to first bake the water simulation and then I can animate other objects.  But that doesn't make sense because tipping the container will change what the water does - and baking the simulation kinda makes that impossible, right?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to keyframe your *Obstacles* and then *Bake*. Make sure your tank never passes through your *Inflow*, if you have one, or is smaller then your *Fluid* can fall into, if you are doing it that way.

[Here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=KegQ-Z1av4c&autoplay=1) is a tutorial on animated *Obstacles*.

Comment: This is definitely what I needed to know. Thanks a bunch. I'll give it a try tonight.

Comment: @PaulG Always glad to help!

Comment: @PaulG Great to hear it!